# To find answers within ourselves

Tags: single-word-requests

Hopefully this is a good attempt in explaining:

I am writing a title for a research. The research studies why exam papers are becoming more difficult over the years according to parent and student ratings.

Most research study and "blame" the school, but my research want to find out if e.g. parents are becoming more protective and students becoming more lazy etc., basically, asking us to "find answer within ourselves".

The research title: Reasons why exams are difficult: A [word request: find answer within ourselves] Perspective.

I have some random words in my head that I am not quite sure how to fit e.g. introspective, self-control, intrinsic, self-determination

Comment: One of the jargon words often used in the field of education is 'reflective'. It might serve.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why those words don't quite fit?

Comment: What do you actually *mean* by "finding answers within oneself"? For most people in most contexts that would imply discovering solutions by introspection. But that has no meaningful connection with *exams*, which are normally intended to establish what you're learned through being ***taught***, not by "navel contemplation".

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Sems to be looking for a noun.

Comment: another word to be considered: idiotropic

Comment: @Rathony - Not exclusively. In the last line of the question. "introspective" and "intrinsic" are adjectives.  Jake - Please can you say whether you want a noun or an adjective. Thanks.

Comment: I took "A" to refer to "Perspective".

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I didn't notice "perspective". Sorry.

Comment: @DanBron I meant, doesn't quite know whether they fit.

Comment: Acccording to your 3rd paragraph ("Most research ..."), what about **behavioural perspective** ot "**menticultural perspective**" ?.

Answer (score 1):

[Self-reflection](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-reflection) seems to be the right word as it involves a process of thinking about your own behavior and beliefs as defined in Merriam Webster.

[Introspection](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/introspection) is synonymous.

[Self-reflection has a broader meaning than introspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_self-reflection)